# Sorting a list of objects by attibute doesn't sort?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

i want to programm a hold'em pokersimulator in python to learn the language (python 3.7). I started by creating a Card-class that contains value (eg. 5 or K) and a suit (eg hearts or spades). A deck of cards is created by matching each value with each suit:

```
suits = ["Hearts","Diamonds","Spades","Clubs"]
values = ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14"] 
#note that i replaced the values J by 10, Q by 11...to later easier compare them
class Card(object):   
    value = 0
    suit = ""

    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

def create_card(value, suit):  
    card = Card(value, suit)
    return card

deck = []
for i in values: 
    for j in suits:
        deck.append(create_card(i,j))

random.shuffle(deck)
```

so now i have a shuffled list of Card-objects and take two cards and assign them to a player. I then draw 5 more cards, the commoncards:

```
player1 = []
for i in range(2):
   player1.append(deck.pop(0))

commoncards = []
for i in range(5):
   commoncards.append(deck.pop(0))
```

Now i have two lists of Card-objects, one for my players wholecards and one for the common cards. So far so good. Now i want to determine the players hand (eg a pair, two pair or three of a kind etc) and i thought a nice way would be to join the players list and a copy of the commoncards list and sort it by value to check if two 'neighbour' elements have the same value:

```
commoncardscopy=commoncards.copy()   
player1.extend(commoncardscopy)

player1.sort(key=lambda Card : Card.value)

for i in range(len(player1)):
    print(player1[i].value)
```

This should print 7 sorted cardvalues (eg 2,2,4,5,8,8,12), right? Well, it doesn't. Here is an example output: 10
13
13
14
7
7
9

Does anyone know why? Any help or feedback is appreciated :)

Comment: Why are your values strings? `'10' < '2'`.

Comment: thats it thanks! i didnt even notice that, wow.

Comment: thanks so much, seriously. i spent waaay too much time thinking on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a good idea to use integers for card values, since if you use strings, cards are sorted in alphabetical order. You might want to use [`int()`](https://kite.com/python/docs/builtins.int) function to do conversions if you want to keep your card values strings. You have couple of options:

- replace `values` with list of integers
- replace code in lambda and use `key = lambda x: int(x.value)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
...
print(sorted([int(i.value) for i in player1]))
```